# How can I create key/keyref XPATH without namespace

Tags: xml, xpath, xsd, keyref

I want to create a set of key/keyref XPATH in xsd schema file without namespace.

The following code doesn't work. Key reference to an unexisting key doesn't give the error. Looks like the XPATH selector or field is not recognized.

```
  xmlns="http://mynamespace"

  <xsd:key name="myId">
    <xsd:selector xpath="./AAA/a"/>
    <xsd:field xpath="@id"/>
  </xsd:key>
  <xsd:keyref name="myIdref" refer="myId">
    <xsd:selector xpath="./BBB/b" />
    <xsd:field xpath="@idref"/>
  </xsd:keyref>
```

I also tries local-name() function like this.

```
<xsd:selector xpath="./*[local-name()='BBB']/*[local-name()='b']" />
```

Got the error:

```
c-general-xpath: The expression './*[local-name()='BBB']/*[local-name()='b']' is not valid with respect to the XPath subset supported by XML Schema.
```

The only way I can make key/keyref work is to include namespace in each element in XPATH, like this:

```
  xmlns:p="http://mynamespace"

  <xsd:key name="myId">
    <xsd:selector xpath="./p:AAA/p:a"/>
    <xsd:field xpath="@id"/>
  </xsd:key>
  <xsd:keyref name="myIdref" refer="p:myId">
    <xsd:selector xpath="./p:BBB/p:b" />
    <xsd:field xpath="@idref"/>
  </xsd:keyref>
```

Is this the only solution? How can I create key/keyref XPATH without namespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set e.g. `<xs:schema xpathDefaultNamespace="http://mynamespace" ...>`, that way your unprefixed element and type names are considered to be in that namespace. But I think this is only supported in XSD 1.1.

Additionally you can change/override your setting of that attribute on a `selector` or `field` element in the schema.

Comment: Thank you very much Martin. I got this error: `Attribute 'xpathDefaultNamespace' cannot appear in element 'schema'`, so I am using XSD 1.0, not 1.1?

Could you tell me how to change/override your setting of that attribute on a selector or field element in the schema.

Comment: Yes, this attribute is new in XSD 1.1 and if it is rejected, that means your schema processor does not recognise XSD 1.1. In XSD 1.1, the attribute can appear either on the element on which the XPath expression appears, or on the `xs:schema` element.

Comment: As for using the `xpathDefaultNamespace` on e.g. `selector`, it would simply be `<xsd:selector xpath="./AAA/a" xpathDefaultNamespace="http://mynamespace"/>`. XSD 1.1 is supported by some special XSD 1.1 release of Xerces Java, by Saxon EE and by Altova, I think.

Comment: Thank you very much, Martin and Michael. I tested it with `xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning" vc:minVersion="1.1" vc:xpathDefaultNamespace="http://mynamespace"`. I can see xpathDefaultNamespace is supported.